# Request headers with S3 static website hosting React app with CloudFront

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a React app deployed to S3 with a CloudFront distribution on top of it for a specific domain CNAME. I want to be able to create a second CloudFront distribution for a separate, different domain but use the same S3 bucket as the origin.

However, in the React app I need to be able to know where the request came from so that the app can dynamically load different data based on that. I found that I can pass on a custom HTTP header from CloudFront to the origin, but that doesn't seem to be accessible from the React code that gets run in the browser.

Is there a way to do this with S3 and CloudFront?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) to handle rendering different components / data based on the route - the docs are quite excellent. I have a React app hosted in S3 behind a CF distribution using React Router and it works excellently.

Comment: Can different CloudFront distributions point to a different React Router route?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of your use case, but Cloudfront distributions can set a default root object - which would let you probably do exactly what you're looking for.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DefaultRootObject.html